# Spring WARNING: Custom isolation level specified but no actual transaction initiated

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, isolation-level, spring-mybatis

After updating spring libraries in our project from version 4.1.6.RELEASE to the latest 4.3.8.RELEASE, a strange WARNING began to pop up. I couldn't find any explanation online so far.

Nothing else but the spring version has changed in the project.

What exactly does this warning mean and why is it popping up? Do we miss some configuration? Our logs are full of it.

Full log message:

```
WARN  2017-04-27 07:59:15 : Custom isolation level specified but no actual transaction initiated; isolation level will effectively be ignored: PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED; '' --- o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager:389 --- [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-93]
```

If you need some specific parts of our configuration, please ask for it.

We are using mybatis as dat alayer (version 3.2.7, and mybatis-spring version 1.2.2)

Comment: It happens there https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java looks like it somehow cannot resolve propagation. Please post your transaction configuration and usage e.g. class which is marked as `@Transactional`